# Opposite to capitalize for Python strings

Tags: python, string

If I want to make a string start with a capital letter, I do

```py
"hello world".capitalize()  # produces 'Hello world'
```

However, I would need the exact opposite: I need to make a string start with a lowercase letter, therefore something like this:

```py
"Hello world".decapitalize()  # produces 'hello world'
"HELLO WORLD".decapitalize()  # produces 'hELLO WORLD'
```

Do we have such a function/method in Python, or it needs to be coded from scratch?

Comment: `lower`?. what should `eBay` change to?

Comment: There is .lower(), but it does the whole string. Otherwise "coding it from scratch" could look like `s[0].lower() + s[1:]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such function in both python2 and python3, so you have to add code it by yourself:

```
def decapitalize(s):
    if not s:  # check that s is not empty string
        return s
    return s[0].lower() + s[1:]
```